# Extract a seris of tar files into self titled directories

Tags: python, tar

I have a series of tar files that I wish to extract their containing data into a new directory. I want this directory to be an edited version of the original tar file name.

```
import tarfile
import glob
import os

for file in glob.glob("*.tar"):
    # Open file
    tar = tarfile.open(file, "r:")
    # Create new diretory with name of tar file (minus .tar)
    new_dir = file[0:-4]
    os.makedirs(new_dir)
    tar.extractall()
    os.chdir(new_dir)
```

This works fine up until the `tar.extractall()` part. Is there a way to directly extract the tar file into the target directory or am I forced to extract all and then move the files across?

Answer (score 0):

new_dir = "path"

`tar.extractall(path=new_dir)`